# Running Junos directly from a USB stick

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I got a Juniper EX2200 switch which is unable to boot, prior to a corrupted flash. The JTAC support is expired and i tried almost everything to get it working again.
I read an article about "Running JunOS directly from an USB stick", but there was no explanation/instructions on how to do this.

Is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can boot JUNOS from a USB drive, and an EX2200 will work.

[Booting an EX Series Switch Using a Software Package Stored on a USB Flash Drive](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.2/topics/task/installation/ex-series-software-installing-booting-from-usb.html)

Follow the documentation and it should work fine.  Chances are your flash isn't permanently corrupt so you can reinstall JUNOS and get everything back in working order.

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions in the following link, but it didn't fix the problem. I'm still getting error messages and it just continues to boot loop.

Comment: Can you paste what you're seeing?

Comment: Never mind, just tried the `loader> install --format --external file:/// ` again. I'm able to access Junos now. But after 2 reboots it went on again, but this time i fixed it again with the above command and were able to update the boot loader.